# How would one convert from FTP to SFTP in a Perl script?

Tags: perl, ftp, sftp

I have an existing Perl script that uses the FTP object to send a couple of files to an AIX box. I just discovered that our Linux box does not support FTP.  It does support SFTP.  What steps should I go through to convert my script to use SFTP?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your current script is probably using the [Net::FTP](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net::FTP) module.  You'll need the [Net::SFTP](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net::SFTP) module and its dependencies from CPAN.  You may just even start a new script using the existing one as a guide.  The logic is the same, though.  Connect, send, and disconnect.

Answer (score 6):

I've actually done something similar. But it was to prepare any current FTP script to be run via SFTP when needed.

I made a wrapper object around [`Net::SFTP`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net::SFTP) which looks and acts like a [`Net::FTP`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net::FTP) object. Therefore, all the calls could be left in places with a different implementation.

I went from this:

```
my $client = Net::FTP->new( Host => 'ftp.somehost.com', ... );
```

to

```
my $client = FTPClient->new( Host => 'ftp.somehost.com', ...
                           , secureFTP => 1 
                           );
```

And just implemented all the methods I was using from [`Net::FTP`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net::FTP) in my new class. [`Net::SFTP`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net::SFTP) gives back some different returns, so you have to actually wrap function instead of just using something like [`Class::Delegator`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Class::Delegator).